# How to read Text between two headings, and return the Heading name for certain pattern matches in the text under that heading

Tags: python

i have a txt file like this :

```
heading 1
 abad askjd asdfj dk skldfj
 askdja ajsdk a ajksdj ajsdk a ajksd
 value yes never dont care about this
 asdj aksjd sd asda sda
 alsdk skldfj sd asda sda
heading 2
 asd asd dfgfd dk a ajksdj
 asdas asd asd sd asda sda
 asdas asdasd dk a ajksdj
 value 123 456 dk a ajksdj
 asdasd asdasd
heading 3
 asd asda sda jsdk a ajksdj
 dsfgd dfgd g dk a aj
 dfgfdg dfgfd dk skldfj
 value yes never dont care about this
 asdasd asdasd gd dfgd g dk
```

So in the above file, i want to get all the headings which have the text "value yes never", so the output with the current file should be :

heading 1
heading 3

How do i go about this in python ?

Comment: so the content between the headings is formatted with spaces. For every line?

Comment: yes, it has a small indent (1 space) for the text between the headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will print out what you want:

```
fname = "file.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    headings = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith(' '):
            current_heading = line.strip()
        else:
            if 'value yes never' in line:
                headings.append(current_heading)

print(headings)
```

If you expect the text "value yes never" to occur on multiple lines between each heading, then you can either deduplicate at the end:

```
print(set(headings))
```

or add a check before appending:

```
if current_heading not in headings:
    headings.append(current_heading)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building a simple loop that iterates over the text line by line.  I'm not sure if the format matches what you posted, but you can do something like the following

```
fname = "file.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
   for line in f:
      if not line.startswith( ' ' ):
         print line
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
    f = open("file.txt",'r')
    headings= []
    headingsCount = 0
    positionOFValueYesNever = []

    for line in f:

       if not line.startswith(' '):
             headings.append(line)
             headingsCount+=1

       elif line.find('value yes never') == True:
             positionOFValueYesNever.append(headingsCount-1)    

    for  i in positionOFValueYesNever:
       print(headings[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` module in order to group the lines within the condition if it starts with a space or not. Then group the result again by two.

This is an example:

```
from itertools import groupby
# Assuming your input file is called: input.txt
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

sub = []
for _, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x.startswith(' ')):
    sub.append([j.strip() for j in list(v)])

final = [sub[k:k+2] for k in range(0, len(sub), 2)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[
 [['heading 1'], ['abad askjd asdfj dk skldfj', 'askdja ajsdk a ajksdj ajsdk a ajksd', '**value yes never** dont care about this', 'asdj aksjd sd asda sda', 'alsdk skldfj sd asda sda']], 
  [['heading 2'], ['asd asd dfgfd dk a ajksdj','asdasasd asd sd asda sda', 'asdas asdasd dk a ajksdj', 'value 123 456 dk a ajksdj', 'asdasd asdasd']], 
  [['heading 3'], ['asd asda sda jsdk a ajksdj','dsfgd dfgd g dk a aj', 'dfgfdg dfgfd dk skldfj', '**value yes never**dont care about this', 'asdasd asdasd gd dfgd g dk']]
]
```